# how to block access of XML file

Tags: php

I created a config file in XML (config.xml)
index.php reads config.xml and gets all configs(database user/pass, and other things).
The problem is if you enter to http://example.com/config.xml you can read all the xml file and that is a security risk.
I tried with chmod 600 but group(apache) cant read the file.
You knows a way to read xml in php and blocks the access outside the server? Thanks for help.

Comment: You should have a directory called `private/`, you can put all secret files in because it can not be accessed via the webbrowser. Talk to your webhoster, this differs by name and location between hosters.

Answer (score 4):

try htaccess.

```
<Files config.xml>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: Better not put these files in locations which can leak when your webserver does not parse .htaccess (any longer?).

Comment: I think your solution should be there in addition to a 750 chmod

Comment: Yes,that's best option. But if he needs file in project itself. :)

Comment: Hosters need to offer more than just a public folder. Most code does not belong into the webroot as well.